# Which definition of noun "glare" fits in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in the chapter "Journey to the end of Earth" which was:

> So there we were, all 52 of us, kitted out in Gore-tax and **glares**, waking on stark whiteness that seemed to spread out forever.

I could not find any definition of noun "glare" that would fit into this context.

Comment: I haven't seen this usage before, but ***Gore-Tex*** (not ***Gore-tax***) refers to clothing material suitable for extremely cold environments. So presumably the "stark whiteness" is ***snow / ice***, and the "glares" are ***dark/reflective glasses / goggles*** worn to protect against [***snow blindness***](https://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/snowblind.htm) in the context of an Arctic expedition.

Comment: I would assume that "Gore-tax" is the authors' way of avoiding the actual brand name in their novel.

Comment: @geekahedron: Nah. No-one would be likely to do that anyway, but [here's a link to the "source"](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p5mapt1/Walk-on-the-ocean-My-Antarctic-experience-was-full-of-such-epiphanies-but-the/), showing that OP has simply mistranscribed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I changed priorities after reading the text again:*

Most likely, it refers to the sunglasses they might be wearing, to protect their vision from damage, due to the strong light.

It might also refer (theoretically) to the frowns of the people, as a result of the bright white reflections of light from the snow. But this explanation does not fit either with "kitted", or with "Gore-tex", so this meaning should be ignored in this context.

Comment: Nah. I don't think ***glare = frown*** is remotely relevant to the context. But your second suggestion hits the mark.

Comment: I read the text again, you are more right then I was. However, I still think that he meaning is 100% guaranteed.

Comment: Well, now you've demoted that irrelevant interpretation to second place, I've removed my downvote. But because it's still present, I won't go so far as to upvote.

Comment: That is downright blackmail! :)

Comment: Yeah, well, I might be harsh, but at least I'm fair (it's harsh treatment for *everyone*, not just you! :) So I won't be upvoting the other answer here either, since it *also* raises that irrelevant interpretation (*and* raises the erroneous possibility that ***glares*** might actually refer to the ambient light rather than protective eyewear).

Comment: Is it not that "kitted up" limits the meaning of "glares" to sunglasses? Even in a novel? If you type "glare" in Google images, you get only sunglasses.

Comment: I had to hunt for *any* reference to "glares" as a term for eyewear, but did eventually find something. And I only mentioned the glare as a facial expression to dismiss it, since it was the first thing mentioned in this (apparently accepted?) answer.

Comment: @geekahedron: in literature, it is common to invent new meaning for existing words, or to invent new words entirely. Actually, it is in the power of the English language to do just that. Think about the fact that "google" cannot be - normally - a verb. But now we have it, documented in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

"Kitted out" refers to what they were wearing. Similarly to "shades" being used as a term for sunglasses, "glares" refers to protective eyewear that is designed for much harsher light (short for "[anti-glare glasses](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-shades-sunglasses-goggles-glares-and-aviators)").

*Edit: This is a usage of the word I had never heard before, and had to search quite a bit to find any other references to "glares" meaning eyewear. That is certainly the case here, though, and I've removed my alternative suggestions to avoid confusion.*